# Matlab Multiple Selection Popup Menu

Tags: matlab

I created a plotter using three popup menus: one for X-variable, one for Y, and one for a figure name.  When a figure name (number) is selected, its callback function grabs strings from X and Y popup menus, search these from a loaded dataset, and plots them on a selected figure.

What I want to do is multiple-selection on a popup menu.  I researched quite a bit and learned that popup menu doesn't have that capability ***in the regular documented way***.

The reason why I don't want to and almost can't use list box is that my GUI has many panels from top to bottom; each containing the three popup menus mentioned above.  Each panel represents one dataset.  This means if I select and load ten .MAT files, a GUI will be created with 10 panels from top to bottom.  Each dataset can have as many as 100 or more variables.  The height of the list box (showing, say, only ten variables) and some margins above and below X (times) 10 will create a gigantic GUI that will be basically unusable.

I came across some java scripting discussion that might work by using JcomboBox with some stern warnings, but I didn't actually find the code of it.

Is there a way?

Imagine in the snapshot below that the drop-down list from the Y-axis popup menu was actually a list box and all panels also have the same height list box.  It'll be very hard to use this tool efficiently.  What I want to do is to select one X-variable, TIME for example (which is the way with popup menu), and be able to select multiple Y-variables.  Then, when I select a figure, the plotter will plot those Y-variables against the selected X-variable.  I can do this iteratively.  Somebody in our group requested this capability and I am scoping its possibility.
[image]

I incorporated @excaza idea and I'm having a hard time to figure out how to retain the selected y variable names while I select a figure for them to be plotted.  See the image below.
[image]

This is definitely going in the right direction.  My problem is now where I can retain the selected index information.  The function below is the callback function of the "Y-axis" pushbutton.  I was thinking about storing the selected y-variable names to its Tag property, but I'm not sure if that's good idea.  I certainly don't want to create a global variable, either.  Any idea?

```
function select_yvar(handle,event,list_yvar)
plot_h = get(get(get(handle.Parent,'Parent'),'Parent'),'Parent');
WinOnTop(plot_h,false);

[yvar_sel,~] = listdlg('Name', 'Variables', 'PromptString', 'Select variable(s)',...
                    'SelectionMode', 'multiple', 'ListString', list_yvar);
```

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to achieve, is there a screenshot of what you want? You could always just make your own popup window, but this whole thing sounds like a UX nightmare. Do you really have the need to plot multiple unique variables per data set and not just the same variables across all of the data sets?

Comment: @excaza Thank you for your response.  I hope my question is more clear now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than trying to hack together some underlying Java that will probably eventually break, I would recommend trying out a popup button that utilizes a [`listdlg`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/listdlg.html).

I've made a toy example GUI that uses the `listdlg` selections to drive what is plotted on the axes. While your application will undoubtedly be different, a similar approach should be able to fit in.

```
classdef testGUI < handle
    properties
        fig
        ax
        xdropdown
        ydropbutt

        data
        plotbool
    end

    methods
        function GUIobj = testGUI()
            initGUI(GUIobj)

            if nargout == 0
                clear GUIobj
            end
        end

        function initGUI(GUIobj)
            GUIobj.data.x = -10:10;
            GUIobj.data.y1 = GUIobj.data.x;
            GUIobj.data.y2 = GUIobj.data.x.^2;
            GUIobj.data.y3 = GUIobj.data.x.^3;
            GUIobj.data.y4 = GUIobj.data.x.^0.5;
            GUIobj.plotbool = false(1, length(fieldnames(GUIobj.data)));

            GUIobj.fig = figure('Name', 'A Plotter', 'NumberTitle', 'off', 'MenuBar', 'none', 'ToolBar', 'none');
            GUIobj.ax = axes('Parent', GUIobj.fig, 'Units', 'Normalized', 'Position', [0.35 0.1 0.60 0.8]);
            GUIobj.xdropdown = uicontrol('Parent', GUIobj.fig, 'Style', 'popupmenu', 'String', 'X', ...
                                         'Units', 'Normalized', 'Position', [0.05 0.5 0.2 0.1]);
            GUIobj.ydropbutt = uicontrol('Parent', GUIobj.fig, 'Style', 'pushbutton', 'String', 'Ydata', ...
                                         'Units', 'Normalized', 'Position', [0.05 0.4 0.2 0.08], ...
                                         'Callback', @(h,e)GUIobj.ydatapopup());
        end

        function ydatapopup(GUIobj)
            [selection, okbool] = listdlg('Name', 'YData', 'PromptString', 'Select Y Data to Plot', ...
                                          'SelectionMode', 'multiple', 'ListString', fieldnames(GUIobj.data), ...
                                          'InitialValue', find(GUIobj.plotbool));
            if okbool
                newplotbool = false(1, length(fieldnames(GUIobj.data)));
                newplotbool(selection) = true;
                GUIobj.plotbool = newplotbool;
                GUIobj.updateplot()
            end
        end

        function updateplot(GUIobj)
            cla(GUIobj.ax);
            hold(GUIobj.ax, 'on')
            fnames = fieldnames(GUIobj.data);
            for ii = 1:length(GUIobj.plotbool)
                if GUIobj.plotbool(ii)
                    plot(GUIobj.data.x, GUIobj.data.(fnames{ii}), 'DisplayName', fnames{ii})
                end
            end
            hold(GUIobj.ax, 'off')
            legend(GUIobj.ax, 'show');
        end
    end
end
```

[image: yay]

Comment: I agree with everything you said.  let me give this a shot.  thank you.

Comment: storing the selected variable names to "Tag" property of the popup menu object is rather unorthodox, but I would call it clever and I'm happy about it.  Thank you.  It's working out quite well.